# onclick function SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I have script that append input to the page and the input with onclick function.
This function get 3 parameters. 
But i get SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script.

my code look like this:

```
scntDiv.append('<input id="coupon_id'+currentItem+'" type="button" value="Create Coupon" onClick="randomString(coupon_id'+currentItem+',ttt'+currentItem+',lll'+currentItem+');">');
```

Any Hellp?

Comment: How does the onclick handler part look like?

Comment: argument inside randomString should be enclosed with quotation, I believe.

Comment: But if i close them i get error.

Comment: Post the whole code please

Comment: if i open firebug i see:
`onclick="randomString(coupon_id2,ttt2,lll2);"`
Instead of:
`onclick="randomString('coupon_id2','ttt2','lll2');"`

Comment: This won't work with vanilla js. Are you using a library such as jQuery? Nevertheless, don't use inline event handlers. Create the element, add the event handler and insert the element into the DOM.

Comment: One can hardly imagine a better case study in why NOT to construct the DOM as long complicated strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax was wrong at the end, here's the right version:

```
scntDiv.append('<input id="coupon_id'+currentItem+'" type="button" value="Create Coupon" onClick="randomString(\'coupon_id'+currentItem+'\',\'ttt'+currentItem+'\',\'lll'+currentItem+'\')">');
```

If you want to use `'` you'll have to escape the character by using `\` like: `\'`

Comment: Thank you very much , Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Though inline handlers work, it would be ideal to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('coupon_id' + currentItem).onclick = function () {
    //your code here
};
```

Or, if you are using jQuery, just

```
$('coupon_id' + currentItem).on('click', function () { /* ... */ });
```